# Oracle GoldenGate Big Data adapter for Kafka Handler

Tags: apache-kafka, oracle-golden-gate

My question is about Kafka checkpointing with replicat,  example, in Kafka producer asynchronous mode, replicat moved to 1 to 100 operations, let say kakfka processed 80 operations, at 81 Kafka is went down for an hour. After Kafka is up, replicat has to reposition from 81st operation. How it is happening with Kafka handler because I did not see any checkpoint and comparison logic mentioned anywhere in GG bigdata adapter oracle websites. What is the guarantee that restart of replicat and adapter starts from 81st operation.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/bd123210/gg-bd/GADBD/using-kafka-connect-handler.htm#GADBD-GUID-81730248-AC12-438E-AF82-48C7002178EC

Answer (score 0):

Checkpointing is handled by Goldengate replicat process in conjunction with Kafka adapters/handlers.Part of Goldengate installation directory there is subdirectories to store files related to Extraction or Replication process and one of the directory is dirchk.

```
 dirchk:

Contains the checkpoint files created by Extract and Replicat processes,which store current read and write positions to support data accuracy and fault tolerance. Written in internal Oracle GoldenGate format.

    File name format is group_name+sequence_number.ext where sequence_number is a sequential number appended to aged files and ext is either cpe for Extract checkpoint files or cpr for Replicat checkpoint files.

            Do not edit these files.

            Examples:

            ext1.cpe

            rep1.cpr
```

You can read about sub directories in Goldengate from this link section A.2

https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1212/gg-winux/GIMSS/installed_components.htm#GIMSS2361

Go through Goldengate related commands or ggsci commands from the link
https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1212/gg-winux/GWURF/ggsci_commands.htm#GWURF884

From above link Section 1.1.3 related to replicat.Some of the important replicat commands are info replicat,lag replicat,synchronize replicat

Read section 10.2 Kafka handlers functionality that explains about check pointing

https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/bd123210/gg-bd/GADBD/using-kafka-handler.htm#GADBD460

Troubleshooting Goldengate kafka handlers by none other than Robin Moffatt :-)

https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2016/09/using-logdump-to-debug-oracle-goldengate-and-kafka/